# Is the Friend/Follow Request working normally on Foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

When I call https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/USER_ID/request it returns the object user, but the friend request is not made properly.

For instance: On behalf of a userA the app calls ".../users/userB_ID/request".
In the response I get a user_object corresponding to userB With relationship == 'pendingThem'.

But userB do not receive any friend request at all.

Any tip? It was working perfectly and just stop working a few days ago.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recently turned off this feature for third parties because we got a number of complaints about spammy friend requests and noticed this endpoint wasn't used too often aside from a few apps that we have a manual override for.

If you'd like your app to be on this manual whitelist for the endpoint, please send an email to api (at) foursquare (dot) com with your client ID and a description of what your app does.